# how reproduce result of powershell > az login in c#?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, command-line-interface

The result of "az login" is list of subscriptions: like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list?source=docs

How to make token for this request without providing tenantId or clientId exactly how it was made on website's login?

I can make token is quite close to required but do not have what I see inside token from website:

```
var functionCred = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId, false);
var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", functionCred).Result;
var token44 = result.AccessToken;
```

What should I do to improve token?

Answer (score 1):

By default, **az login** command logs in with a user account. CLI will try to launch a web browser to log in interactively, if browser is not available then CLI will fall back to device code login.

For the question -

> How to make token for this request without providing tenantId or clientId exactly how it was made on website's login?

It is not feasible to get an authentication token without using tenantId and clientId. Mostly token is generated by client id and secret. Token can be acquired via app registration + tenentId or user credentials + tenentId.

Below code snippet shows how you get the access token using Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL).

```cs
static AuthenticationResult AccessToken() 
{ 
    string resourceUri = "https://datacatalog.azure.com";

    // register a client app and get a Client ID
    string clientId = clientIDFromAzureAppRegistration; 

    //A redirect uri gives AAD more details about the specific application that it will authenticate. 
    string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"; 

    // Create an instance of AuthenticationContext to acquire an Azure access token 
    string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri); 

    // AcquireToken takes a Client Id that Azure AD creates when you register your client app. 
    return authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), PromptBehavior.RefreshSession); 

}
```

For more information check this [Steps to get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/authenticate-a-client-app#c-example---get-access-token) section of the Microsoft Document.

Comment: ----"It is not feasible to get an authentication token without using tenantId and clientId. "    .  I know this documentation and how "az login" works.  Somehow powershell can do this for my tenant account.    Once I can login into Azure - this quite logical to get credentials I just confirmed.